# Are there any GUI/WYSIWYG CMS editor based on Jekyll?

Tags: content-management-system, jekyll, wysiwyg

I find Jekyll to be very easy and useful to maintain static html sites and blogs, especially along with GitHub pages. Wanted to know if there are any Static site generators or CMS which helps in maintaining Jekyll sites with live preview, inline editing, layout management, file management etc.

Comment: I think https://www.JekyllPad.com could be what you are looking for

Answer (score 12):

There's an emerging market of "headless CMS" services that let you (or other writers) edit content through a web interface, and then access this content via an API.  Most have webhooks that could be used to trigger regeneration of the static site when the content stored in the CMS is changed.  Libraries for jekyll integrations already exist for these platforms.

List of headless CMSes:

- [Prismic](https://prismic.io) ([jekyll library](https://github.com/CHH/jekyll-prismic))
- [Contentful](https://contentful.com) ([jekyll library](https://github.com/dommmel/jekyll-contentful))
- [Osmek](http://osmek.com/)
- [Storyblok](https://www.storyblok.com) ([jekyll integration](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/headless-cms-jekyll))
- others

Comment: I don't see any open source alternative here... and didn't find much from a quick search. Sad in a way.

Comment: I agree though, it would be great if there was an open source option maintained by an organization that also offered a hosted plan.

Comment: @PatrickSteadman I think http://getdirectus.com/ could be what you want

Answer (score 9):

A few cool products fit the bill here:

- CloudCannon
- Siteleaf
- Forestry.io
- DatoCMS
- Netlify CMS
- jekyll-admin

Most of them sync directly with Git so devs can push directly on the repo, and non-techie users indirectly do the same by saving content (which trigger builds) in simpler UIs.

I personally like CloudCannon for its easy, more "visual" approach to editing stuff for non-technical folks (one of our dev wrote a full tuts on [using CC + Jekyll for a multilingual site](https://snipcart.com/blog/cms-jekyll-cloud-cannon-multilingual), should it be helpful).

Netlify CMS' open source approach is pretty neat too. The CMS is basically a react app you inject in any project.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

I have found these solutions:

- http://www.siteleaf.com/
- http://cloudcannon.com/

The second seems to be more promising to me. We basically want to develop the jekyll templates on our side, but want to have the possiblity for non-coders to edit the content online.

If you don't want to pay and you are okay with hosting a solution or do the editing offline, then you could try out this one: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-admin (Although I haven't tried it, but if you do, please share your experiences with me.)

Comment: Just found Siteleaf through this comment and have to say it seems to fit the bill perfectly. Planning to try it out but I really really like that the developer version (which allows you to push to GitHub still) is free. You’ll only need to pay if you need to preview your site before pushing your change.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished with a simple editor for the same. You can find it on github [here](https://github.com/georoot/jekyll.js). It is still in initial release stage but it does come with live preview for editing posts on jekyll and managing them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching for the same, as all Static site generators I found require Markdown knowledge which isn't suitable at all for my clients.
I found this great CMS (Kinda!) https://sitecake.com/

Still don't know how to manage collections with it, say listing of few products with lightbox details, but I believe it is possible.